# How to send custom headers in OpenURI (Ruby) and check them

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, open-uri

Found this in the following doc: https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI.html

> Additional header fields can be specified by an optional hash argument.
>
> ```
>  open("http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/",
>    "User-Agent" => "Ruby/#{RUBY_VERSION}",
>    "From" => "foo@bar.invalid",
>    "Referer" => "http://www.ruby-lang.org/") {|f|
>    # ...
>  }
> ```

Can someone tell me how to check whether this is working properly?

Comment: The first thing to know is that OpenURI is one of the most used pieces of code in Ruby's HTTP toolkit, and it has a lot of scrutiny and testing. As a result, the odds are _REALLY_ good it's doing what it's supposed to. So let's turn this around and do it the Stack Overflow way: show us what you're doing and explain why you think it's not doing what you want. See "[mcve]" and "[ask]" including the linked pages.

Answer (score 3):

> Can someone tell how to check whether they [the additional header fields] are properly working.

You could use [netcat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat) to listen on a specific port, say 2000:

```sh
$ nc -l 2000
```

And change the host accordingly to `localhost:2000`:

```
# open.rb
require 'open-uri'

open("http://localhost:2000/",
  "User-Agent" => "Ruby/#{RUBY_VERSION}",
  "From" => "foo@bar.invalid",
  "Referer" => "http://www.ruby-lang.org/") {|f|
   # ...
}
```

Running the program via

```
$ ruby open.rb
```

Will make netcat show this:

```
$ nc -l 2000
GET / HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Ruby/2.3.1
From: foo@bar.invalid
Referer: http://www.ruby-lang.org/
Accept-Encoding: gzip;q=1.0,deflate;q=0.6,identity;q=0.3
Accept: */*
Host: localhost:2000
```

Apparently, the headers are working properly. (of course they do)